# Unique limits of sequences wrt different topologies.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ on which there are defined two topologies $T_1,T_2$. If $(a_n)$ converges to a unique limit $x_1$ wrt $T_1$, and to a unique limit $x_2$ wrt $T_2$, is it necessary that $x_1=x_2$? If not are there any nice counter-examples?

I have tried to show that this is false using a counter-example, by "interchanging" two points in $X$. Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $T_1$ to be the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, so that the sequence $(2^{-n})$ converges uniquely to $0$ wrt $T_1$. Now "interchange" $1$ and $0$ when defining $T_2$:

$O\in T_2$ iff one of the following:

1) $O\in T_1$ and $0,1\notin O$

2) $O\in T_1$ and $0,1\in O$

3) $(O\backslash\{0\})\cup\{1\} \in T_1$ and $0\in O,1\notin O$

4) $(O\backslash\{1\})\cup\{0\} \in T_1$ and $0\notin O,1\in O$

This is a topology and the aforementioned sequence converges uniquely to $1$ wrt $T_2$. Is this method right? Are there more elegant examples?

Comment: Boring counterexample: Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $T_1$ the usual topology, and $T_2$ induced by the metric $d(x,y) = \lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert$ where $f$ swaps $0$ and $\pi$ and leaves everything else fixed. Then $a_n = 2^{-n}$ converges to $0$ in $T_1$ and to $\pi$ in $T_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example: consider $X=\mathbb{N}$ and for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ define $T_k$ to be the smallest topology generated by

$$\text{the interval }[k, \infty)$$
$$\text{almost all singletons }\big\{\{s\}_{s\neq k}\big\}$$

Now consider the sequence $a_n=n$. It can be easily seen that the only two open subsets containing $k$ are $[k,\infty)$ and $X$ and thus $a_n$ converges to $k$ in $T_k$. On the other hand every other point is an open singleton and since $a_n$ is not (eventually) constant then $a_n$ cannot converg to anything other then $k$.

Answer (score 0):

$X=\{a,b\}$ $T_1=\{a,b\}, \{a\}$ and $T_2=\{a,b\}, \{b\}$ $a_{2n}=a, a_{2n+1}=b$.